# Google Play Game Services shows only first letter of profile name

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

I have recently followed the Google Play Game Services tutorial: https://developers.google.com/games/services/training/signin

And I have a full RealTime Multiplayer connection with the game services client.  My problem is when using this:

```
if(Games.Players.getCurrentPlayer(game.mGoogleClient).getDisplayName().length() >= 4) {
        this.displayName = Games.Players.getCurrentPlayer(game.mGoogleClient).getDisplayName().substring(0, 4);
    }
    else {
        this.displayName = Games.Players.getCurrentPlayer(game.mGoogleClient).getDisplayName();
    }
```

in my game screen class constructor, and sending the aforementioned string to my `paint()` method, it only displays the first letter of my Google Plus (displayed) name (An "A" on the screen).

EDIT: Here is my Google Client build:

```
this.mGoogleClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this, this, this)
    .addApi(Games.API)
    .addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
    .setViewForPopups(this.findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button))
    .setGravityForPopups(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL)
    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
    .build();
```

#### Thoughts on possible solutions:

-Can I add more than one scope? I may need to add `.addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)` although I already have `.addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)`

-Since I am saving the name in my game screen constructor, is it not waiting to read the full name before the constructor ends?

-I need to enter some sort of SHA1 key? I install the game directly from the Google Play Store so I get the actual user experience and so I don't accidentally check the debugging .apk, but I have all the required APIs turned on on my Developer's Console

-Following up on the key idea, could the data from the Google Client be encoded in such a way that it needs special authorization?  Again, I have set XML permissions, turned on required APIs and added the game to the Google Play Game Services section of the Developer's Console, as specified in the tutorial.

-Along with the encoding idea, could this display name just not be readable as text?
Thanks, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using the `substring()` method?

Comment: I actually have this in an if statement so that if the String is longer than 4 characters, it will be truncated, else it is less than 4 characters and just set it equal to displayName.

Comment: I think that's where your problem is.Something might be wrong with the logic.

Comment: I have added the if and else statements above.  Unless there is something wrong with getting the length of the displayName, it should be alright though.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I need this code because I'm creating a multiplayer game and I would like the name to be displayed above the head of the player on screen, no more than 4 letters.

Comment: Also, the substring method is one less than the final character, I have tested it on an online compiler and (0,4) should give me 4 letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call off the search party!  I had completely forgotten the Font Class that I made only uses uppercase letters, and clearly all sorts of mixed cases could occur for display names.  Thanks for helping, the code above is pretty much flawless.  If I'm not mistaken, the display name also gets both the first and last name with a space in between.